# Experiences I have had vs experiences I have had before (tenses)

Tags: grammar, tense

When someone asks you this:

> Question: Do you like love songs?
>
> Answer#1: Yes I do, because sometimes I relate to the song's lyrics, especially the experiences that I have had **before**.

To

> Answer#2: Yes I do, because sometimes I relate to the song's lyrics, especially the experiences that I have had.

Is there any differences between the two? And why do they have to include **before**? (mostly at the end of a sentence/statement) When it is obviously in the past?

Comment: The meaning doesn't change.  Using "before" is just a little more wordy than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is redundant, but it is common to use the "before" in that sentence. Maybe an over-communication, but it's very common.